# How to load multiple images for processing with opencv?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a code in OpenCV C++ and I have to apply to twenty or more images. Now I'm debbuging one by one, changing the name of the image every time. Is there a way that I can, like, call all the images and submit them to that process and save all of them?

I'm using this:

```
Mat input_image = imread("img1.jpg");
```

for load a image. And this:

```
imwrite("output_image.jpg", output_image);
```

for save the image in my project folder.

---

Update:

I did this but it didn't work:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    char name[50];
    int i=0;
    Mat output_image;

    while(1){

        sprintf(name, "cam%d.jpg", i);

        //Load the image
        Mat input_image = imread(name, 1);
        if(!input_image.data) break;

        //Image RGB to Grayscale
        cvtColor(input_image, output_image, CV_RGB2GRAY);

        //Applying Gaussian
        GaussianBlur(output_image, output_image, Size(21.0, 21.0), 50.0);

        //applying adaptive threshold
        adaptiveThreshold(output_image, output_image, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 111, -20);

        sprintf(name,"cam%d-bin.jpg",i);

        //save the image
        imwrite(name, output_image);

        i++;


    }

}
```

Comment: You could do it in a loop..

Comment: Did you try what I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code. Assume that your image names like img0.jpg, img1.jpg, img2.jpg etc...

```
char name[10];
int i=0;
Mat gray;
while(1){  

    sprintf(name,"img%d.jpg",i);
    Mat src= imread(name,1);
     if(!src.data ) break;

     cvtColor(src,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
     sprintf(name,"gray%d.jpg",i);
     imwrite(name, gray);

    imshow("src",src);
    imshow("result",gray);

    i++;
    waitKey();
}
```

Comment: please, check my update. I tried what you said, but didn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the images are in current directory ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
const char* DATASET("D:/Data/input_image_directory/");
const int total_images = 20;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string file_directory;
    int count;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        file_directory = argv[1];
        count = argv[2];
    }
    else
    {
        file_directory = DATASET->c_str();
        count = total_images;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
    {
        // This is assuming your file names are in the structure image000.png, image001.png,...
        cv::Mat input_Mat = cv::imread( cv::format( "%s/image%03d.png", file_directory, i ), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR );
        cv::namedWindow ("input_image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cv::imshow( "input_image", input_Mat);

        // Do processing
        // Some more processing
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```